# Heroku + Rails 3.1: asset_path undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

i try to deploy a rails 3.1.3 app to heroku but keep getting the following error when browsing the pages:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `asset_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000002ecd630>:0x00000002e52480>):
```

i use the "cedar" stack as recommended by heroku. any idea why i get this issue? do i have to make some more configuration?

thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** works again. i forgot to add "require 'sprockets/railtie'" in the application.rb...

Comment: Does this work if you run it in production mode locally?

Comment: good point. no it doesn't work in production locally. any suggestion what i do wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add "require 'sprockets/railtie'" in the application.rb