# Rails - Url to a Static Assets in /Public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, erb, assets

I'm using S3 to serve my public folder & trying to build a simple URL to one of these assets.

My production.rb has:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

And this works perfect in my .erb files:

```
<%= image_tag("rails.png") %>
# => <img src="https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/rails.png" />
```

But I need a url (not a tag) for a GENERIC file type, like:

```
<%= asset_host "foo.bar" %>
# => https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/foo.bar
```

What is the magic, two-word, underscore joined, rails phrase that gives me this url?

Answer (score 2):

Use `<%= asset_path "foo.bar" %>`.

Comment: i get the error `undefined method 'asset_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faf1b9f6268>:0x007faf18b9cf98>`

Comment: yeah, `gem 'rails', '3.2.0'` - i'm sure i'm missing something dumb, just don't know what it is

Comment: Yeah, in fact here is the tutorial I was following: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31

Comment: You might need to add `require 'sprockets/railtie'` to your `application.rb`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443117/heroku-rails-3-1-asset-path-undefined